# 2014 haskell cabal update hangs on mac

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-platform, cabal-install

I initially installed haskell platform ( 2013 version; 7.6.3 ghc ) on my mac. Everything was working great. Just now saw the haskell platform website again and found new version was released ( Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0 for Mac OS X, 64bit ). I installed it, and un-installed the older version using uninstall-hs.

Now when i type "cabal" or "cabal update" on my terminal, it hangs. Actually when i look into Activity Monitor, i can see that it is invoking some "sh script & possibly some find command" infinitely. I initially guess may be it is building some indexes. but it has been running for an hr or so.

Please advice. I cannot install any other package using cabal.

Comment: Did you remove your `.cabal` and `.ghc` folders before installing the new version? I don't know the location on Mac OSX, but probably something like `Library/Haskell` and `~/Library/Haskell`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Zeta, you can remove (or to be safe, backup) ~/.cabal and ~/.ghc first. I also have a Mac OS X 10.9.4 and recently upgraded. I ran the uninstall-hs script, and installed the new Haskell Platform 2014. Even without backing up those directories though, I still had an event free uninstall/update.

Also, ensure to double check your paths in your ~/.bash_profile, as they will need to be updated.

Here is an example of mine, to hopefully give you some clues as what may need to be done.

```
# Haskell / Cabal
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/lib/cabal-install-1.20.0.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.emacs.d/hslint:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/lib/cgrep-6.4.4/bin:$PATH"
```

As for cabal try `$ which cabal` and `cabal -V` to verify you are running the latest 1.20 cabal version and that it's set in your $PATH.